# Stripes vs Batch in ORC & Partitions in Parquet

Tags: bigdata, parquet, orc

I am new to Big Data, trying to understand different file formats from  better query executions perspective , while trying to understand more about layout of the files of ORC & Parquet, came across the below terminology and wanted to validate my understanding.

1. Stripes - as per my understanding they are group of rows which belongs to same data set, for example if we have data for a different countries in a 
   file , the data for each country is in one Stripe , this helps in reducing the amount of data transferred from disk to memory as the Stripes not relevant can be skipped using Predicate push down.
2. VectorizedRowBatch  , this helps in vectorization of columnar data for efficient CPU processing . it processes Batch by batch. in this context I could not understand the difference between Stripes & Batch. As I understood stripes helps to reduce the amount of data being transferred from disk to Memory , while Batch helps in processing the records paralelly using vectorization approach.

3.Stripes are only specific to ORC file format , similar concept for Parquet files is "Partitions" which is related data stored in RowGroups. which helps in Predicate push down.

for Parquet we do not have vectorization support , does that mean that ORC is better compared to Parquet for better CPU utilization.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong for the points mentioned.